# mybatis passing in the datatype on dynamic update query

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I am trying to create a dynamic update statement using [dynamic-sql](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) method and [sql-builder](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html) method but I only manage it get it work for `string` datatype. I'm not exactly sure how to "cast" to the correct datatype when constructing the update statement.

What I want to achieve is to generate the update statement using `Map<String, Object>` or the actual pojo `Post`

`Post` look like this

```java
public class Post {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String body;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String createdBy;
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    private String updatedBy;
}
```

Reason for `Map<String, Object>` is so that it's easier to iterate through the collection and construct the statement. Using the pojo would require me to use `reflection` which I try not to.

Before getting into how I did it

This is how when using a normal update statement with the pojo looks like

```java
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public Post updateById(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Post post) {
    return this.postService.updateById(id, post);
}

@Update("UPDATE POST SET title = #{p.title}, body = #{p.body}, createdAt = #{p.createdAt}, createdBy = #{p.createdBy}, updatedAt = #{p.updatedAt}, updatedBy = #{p.updatedBy} WHERE id = #{id}")
public boolean updateById(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("p") Post post);
```

That would result in

```
2021-10-30 12:03:15.037 DEBUG 15988 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET title = ?, body = ?, createdAt = ?, createdBy = ?, updatedAt = ?, updatedBy = ? WHERE id = ?
2021-10-30 12:03:15.064 DEBUG 15988 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==> Parameters: jsonpatch1(String), bo21(String), 2021-10-30T12:03:14.954483(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 2021-10-30T12:03:14.954483(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 65(Integer)
```

So with that, I tried to do this

```java
// What this does is to strip off all the null values, and keep only those with value
// and convert into a map to pass and run in the dynamic sql later
@PatchMapping(path = "/{id}")
public Post patchById(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Post post) {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    om.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    om.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    Map<String, Object> mp = om.convertValue(post, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
    return this.postService.patchById(id, mp);
}
```

Where it goes to a `mapper` that looks something like this

```java
@Update({
    "<script>",
    "UPDATE POST",
    "<set>",
    "<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='p.entrySet()'>",
    "${index} = #{item},",
    "</foreach>",
    "</set>",
    "WHERE id = #{id}",
    "</script>"
})
public boolean update(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("p") Map<String, Object> post);
```

This works if all the values are `string`. However, if there is a field of `LocalDateTime createdAt`, the `createdAt` field is deem as a `string` type

```
021-10-30 15:21:27.666 DEBUG 12324 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostUpdateMapper.update     : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET createdAt = ?, title = ?, body = ? 
WHERE id = ?
2021-10-30 15:21:27.669 DEBUG 12324 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostUpdateMapper.update     : ==> Parameters: 2021-09-10T11:31:07.5306869(String), jsonpatch1(String), bo221(String), 65(Integer)
```

I believe, that is because I switch it to `Map<String, Object>` and hence the type (LocalDateTime) is loss with the conversion. However, if I were to do it using the pojo `Bean`

I would have something like this

```java
@PatchMapping(path = "/{id}")
public Post patchById(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Post post) {
    return this.postService.patchById(id, post);
}

@UpdateProvider(type=SQLUpdate.class, method = "update")
public boolean update(Integer id, Post post);

// just a poc to see if it works
public String update(Integer id, Post post) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] f = post.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    return new SQL() {{
        UPDATE("POST");
        for(Field field: f) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(post) != null) {
                SET(field.getName() + " = '" + field.get(post) + "'");
            }
        }
        WHERE("id = " + id);
    }}.toString();
}
```

So either way, I'm not sure how to pass in the correct type so that it can intercept and run correctly

---

This would be the more ideal solution if I can achieve this

```java
@Update({
    "<script>",
    "UPDATE POST",
    "<set>",
    // being able to check if the value is null and set the field and value dynamically
    "<if test='#{p.value} != null>p.fieldname = #{p.value}",
    "</set>",
    "WHERE id = #{id}",
    "</script>"
})
public boolean update(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("p") Post post);
```

Let me know if more information is needed, or if there is a better way to achieve what I want to do

Thanks!

P.S: I know and I got it working with [mybatis-dynamic-sql](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/docs/introduction.html) lib but interested to know if it cab work without using the lib

Comment: It probably is the `ObjectMapper` that converts `LocalDateTime` to `String`. Try preparing the map without using `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Thanks @ave, I will give it a try. never thought of that. Just to also check, do I need to enclose quote when passing to `item (${index} = '#{item}')?

Comment: I know why I didn't look into doing it without `ObjectMapper`. Because, to convert to `Map`, I would still need to do it via `Reflection` or using custom serializer/deserializer if I still want to use `ObjectMapper` right?

Comment: Quotes are unnecessary. The driver takes care of it. To convert a POJO into a `Map`, you may need to use reflection one way or another. There might be a way to customize the `ObjectMapper`'s behavior. Or, you can look for another tool to do that conversion. I just wanted to point out that MyBatis does not convert `LocalDateTime` into `String` by itself.

Comment: Thanks. Was trying to see if there's any other way that I haven't thought of. You mean that if I were to pass a `LocalDateTime` object as the parameter, it wouldn't auto convert to `String` right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.